# Group multiple properties with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to group and count the array below by `id` and `name`

```
var arr = [
        {
            id: 'A1',
            name: 'andersson'
        },
        {
            id: 'A1',
            name: 'johansson'
        },
        {
            id: 'A1',
            name: 'andersson'
        },
    ];
```

Expected output:

```
var aggregated = [
            {
                id: 'A1',
                name: 'andersson',
                count: 2
            },
            {
                id: 'A1',
                name: 'johansson',
                count: 1
            }
        ];
```

This should be a basic task but I cant find any handy way to do it with underscore. The `_.groupBy` function should probably be used somehow.

My dataset is big so performance is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first `groupBy` id and count and then use `map` to count each value.

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 'A1',
  name: 'andersson'
}, {
  id: 'A1',
  name: 'johansson'
}, {
  id: 'A1',
  name: 'andersson'
}];

var result = _.chain(arr)
  .groupBy(e => e.id + '|' + e.name)
  .map(e => (e[0].count = e.length, e[0]))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice. Possible to make generic so all properties in the object are grouped?